# Could C++ implement type array?

Tags: c++, c++17

Like this:

```
typeArray type[2] = {uint8_t, uint16_t};
for (int i=0; i < 2; i++)
{
    myFunction<type[i]>();
}
```

I think it is impossible to implementation, because it break some rules in C++. But I'm not sure, and I'm not familiar with the new features of C++(11 14 17 etc.). so could anyone tell me the answer?

More specific.

```
\\ Such as I have a template functon "PrintSecondTypeLen"
template<typename Type>PrintSecondTypeLen(unsigned int *a)
{
    Type *b;
    b = (Type *) a;
    std::cout << *(b+1) << std::endl;
}
\\ Then suppose that I have a typeArray.
typeArray type[2] = {uint8_t, uint16_t}; \\ It's wrong, just for example.

\\ Then I use it:
unsigned int a[2] = {0x56575859, 0x46474849};
for (int i=0; i < 2; i++)
{
    PrintSecondTypeLen<type[i]>(a);
}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. What operations do you want the array to support? You can use something like `using type_list = std::tuple<uint8_t, uint16_t>;` instead of the array and loop over it, but you can't modify such a list at runtime.

Comment: What about simply an array of pointers of some superclass and then calling an overridden method from the object you are storing?

Comment: @Aziuth I implement smilar function with function pointer, now that we must determind the type of value, I just implement all type of function I will use, then save them in a function pointer array, then I use index to call this arrays. Of course, the type of input parameters must be same, but I have not better way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++ types are not first-class values at runtime. You can have type lists at compile time for template metaprogramming but not a run time.

Your "loop" could be implemented with a variadic template but expanding it at compile time, not at run time.

May be (may be) types as first-class values is something will be introduced with reflection in C++23. In which form and what will you be able to do with it is another issue.

The main problem for C++ on this is that types do no actually exist in a compiled program. Types in a sense are part of the **code** and a compiled program doesn't deal with code but with **data** (in C++ data is not code and code is not data; this "barrier" will not be easy to break also for psychological reasons).

Answer (score -1):

> Could C++ implement type array?

C++ has already [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) standard containers.

Notice that in C++17, types are not really first class citizens. But see also the  [`<typeinfo>` standard header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/typeinfo).

You might store *some* type information (at least if you have some `virtual` member function), but the issue is, given an instance of `std::typeinfo`, to obtain a value of that type.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question is somewhat ambiguous. I don't want a array to store data in some types, I want a array to store **type**.